# Remove character by index in Java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to remove a character by index in a string. Here is a my source:

```
 private String removeByIndex(String str, int index) {
    return str.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(str.charAt(index)), "");
}
```

My input string is, for example, `1.05`. My goal is to receive `1.5`, by removing the first element after the dot.

I called this function like this

```
removeByIndex("1.05",Stringlength-2)
```

but the result is `1`.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Please post an example invocation of the function that reproduces the problem

Comment: I called this function like this  removeByIndex("1.05",length-2) but result is 1.

Comment: Your code working fine for me

Comment: I tried the same function you wrote, result was 1.5 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach works. Just need to find the position for the dot.

```
class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        String str = "1.05";
        int dotPos = str.indexOf(".");


        String res = Playground.removeByIndex(str, dotPos + 1);

        System.out.println(res);

    }

    private static String removeByIndex(String str, int index) {
        return str.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(str.charAt(index)), "");
    }
}
```

You could also use StringBuilder for this:

```
class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        String str = "1.0505";
        int dotPos = str.indexOf(".");


        String res = Playground.removeByIndex(str, dotPos + 1);

        System.out.println(res);

    }

    private static String removeByIndex(String str, int index) {
        return new StringBuilder(str).deleteCharAt(index).toString();
    }
}
```

*Edit1*: Adds another example which works with any position and any character

Comment: Now it doesn't as it always removes the first occurrence of duplicated character. It will fail for `1.0505` input with remove at index `5`.

Comment: Yes, as @KarolDowbecki says, `replaceFirst` is not really a good option here. Another example that fails when trying to remove the digit after the `.` would be `201.05`.

Comment: You are right, but in the example he only wanted to remove the char after dot. And there is only one dot. I added another example on how to do this if there could be multiple matching characters and it doesn't need to be the first.

Answer (score 7):

Try this any digit after dot will be replaced with dot only

```
private String removeByIndex(String str, int index) {
    return str.replaceFirst("\\.[\\d]", ".");
}
```

Comment: You need to escape that first `.` in your regexp (`"\\.[\\d]"`). Otherwise the `.` will match any character.  As it is, if you call your method on `"12.05"`, it will return `"..05"`.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the index you should use `String.substring(int start, int end)` to cut your input. This can be folded into [`StringBuilder.append(String s, int start, int end)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int)):

```
private static String removeByIndex(String str, int index) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  if (index > 0) {
    sb.append(str, 0, index);
  }
  if (index < str.length() - 1) {
    sb.append(str, index + 1, str.length());
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Or as pointed by [pascalpuetz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49573699/1602555):

```
private static String removeByIndex(String str, int index) {
    return new StringBuilder(str).deleteCharAt(index).toString();
}
```

Comment: You're already using StringBuilder - why not use the `deleteCharAt(index)` method?

Comment: @pascalpuetz I simply wasn't aware of it, thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

your code is working fine.

```
public class hr1{
 private static String removeByIndex(String str, int index) {
        return str.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(str.charAt(index)), "");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="1.05";
    int inde=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if(s.charAt(i)=='.')
            break;
        inde++;
    }
    String res=removeByIndex(s,inde+1);
    System.out.println(res);
}
}
```